# Remove double 301 redirect from my htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I just realized that my htaccess produces double 301 redirect in some cases. For example, if you try to access http://example.com/old_url it will:

- First 301 to  http://www.example.com/old_url (added www)
- Then 301 to http://www.example.com/new_url (changed to new url)

Here's how my htaccess is set up:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]

# Do some url rewriting
RewriteRule ^new_url_1$ new_url_1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^new_url_2$ new_url_2.php [NC,L]

# Do the 301 redirections
Redirect 301 /old_url_1 http://www.example.com/new_url_1
Redirect 301 /old_url_2 http://www.example.com/new_url_2
```

How can I fix that to have only one 301 for better SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `Redirect` directives with `mod_rewrite` rules and keep specific redirect rules before `www` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

# Do specific 301 redirections
RewriteRule ^old_url_1$ http://www.example.com/new_url_1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^old_url_2$ http://www.example.com/new_url_2 [L,NC,R=301]

# Add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Do some url rewriting
RewriteRule ^new_url_1$ new_url_1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^new_url_2$ new_url_2.php [NC,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What's the difference between `Redirect 301 /old_url_1 http://www.example.com/new_url_1` and `RewriteRule ^old_url_1/?$ http://www.example.com/new_url_1 [L,NC,R=301]`?

Comment: `RewriteRule` is mod_rewrite directive and `Redirect` is from `mod_alias`. Different modules are executed at different times and mixing them together can cause problems.

Comment: And what about the specific differences between the two? You added "/?" in the url and also "L,NC" as options. Does that change anything?

Comment: No `/?$` just allows an optional trailing slash. `NC` is for ignore case matching and `L` is for ending a rule.

Comment: Last question, if I wanted to remove the potential trailing slash from the new url, I should add this rule just before the "add www" rule? `RewriteRule ^new_url/$ http://www.example.com/new_url [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: I've added a rule in answer to remove trailing slash.