# Prevent double 301 redirects in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Here is my current .htaccess file code.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

  # First rewrite to HTTPS:
  # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
  # the subsequent rule will catch it.
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note : I have checked this question - [Remove double 301 redirect from my htacess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328628/3113599)
But it doesn't apply here as there is no `Redirect` in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to avoid double 301 redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.